# Send data from controller to form type

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.5

I have a question regarding manage forms in symfony2. So in my controller I have :

```
$form = $this->createForm(SubMenuType::class);
```

In the SubMenuType class I have :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $aTemplate  = Template::$aTemplates;
    $aMenu = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppAdminBundle:Menu')->findAll();
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('template',ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => $aTemplate,'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('menu',ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => $aMenu,'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class, array('label'=> 'Save'))
    ;
}
```

The question is : How to get in `$aMenu` data from Menu entity in this `SubMenuType` ? Please help me. Thx in advance

Comment: What you mean saying: *"How to get in $aMenu data from Menu entity in this SubMenuType" *?

Comment: @felipsmartins how to use `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppAdminBundle:Menu')->findAll()` in SubMenuType ?

Comment: Okay, if I understand it well it should be helpful (I've answered it before): [Load options into drop down on a form based on user's id in symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001245/load-options-into-drop-down-on-a-form-based-on-users-id-in-symfony-2/30001361) or [aaaa][Symfony forms (as standalone component with Doctrine) EntityType not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727135/symfony-forms-as-standalone-component-with-doctrine-entitytype-not-working/34731619#34731619)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is using the `EntityType` form type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $aTemplate  = Template::$aTemplates;
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('template',ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => $aTemplate,'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('menu', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppAdminBundle:Menu', 
            'choice_label' => 'property of your menu entity you want as label'
        ))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class, array('label'=> 'Save'))
    ;
}
```